# MVC page loading very slowly. How can I pinpoint the issue?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very basic MVC page.  All it does is reads the url the user is using, pulls the subdomain from the url, compares that subdomain against some values in a database, & then redirects to another page. But it's loading very slow.  About 30 seconds. There's very little to my code.  It has something to do with what's loading ahead of time.

[You can try the link here to see for yourself](http://ryanmatthews.niagaragradschool.com)

In my tests, it takes about 30 seconds to load initially.  If I try it multiple times, it's fine.  It's just that 1st load.  In my debugging, I experience the same problem.  It's something during loading because the slowdown happens before I hit my 1st line of code.

How can I determine where the issue's coming from?  I do see visual studio 2015 loaded a TON of DLL's into my MVC project when I created it, many of which I'm not using.  Could this be the culprit?  Here are most of them:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, when I compiled & published to my web server (see link in my original message), it still loads in about 30 seconds

Comment: After seeing your site, I checked the network which shows your css files are taking too much time to load. So better include those css in your local solution rather than calling it through a url path 'linked_coffeegrinder.min.css'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely get rid of some of those references.

There is one thing to keep in mind though.

The first time you run your website the code will be compiled, files copied over to the ASP.Net Temporary Folder ( 32 or 64 bit version ). This part will always introduce a delay.

When you run the website for real, as in from a proper server and IIS, the same thing will happen, the first request takes a bit of time to load. Subsequent calls will be instant as all the files are available, until there is a gap in usage. If your website is not used for a period of 20 minutes, let's say, the first request after that will again take some time.

You can speed up the bits which are within your control, like the size of the page, how many libraries you're loading, how big they are, images etc. There are online tools around which will give you an indication of where to look. YSLow is such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, if you are only using Razor as your view engine, then remove the WebForms view engine.

See this article http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/aDN4031112-Removing-the-Web-Form-View-Engine-for-better-performance-of-Razor-View-Engine.html

Comment: You can also try to diagnose the execution of your MVC application using a tool like Glimpse or Stackify Prefix.

Comment: The difference should be minimum. Unless you have thousands of users connected a the same time this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pictures are what's slowing you down (campus background, graduate viewbook, etc.). These get cached locally and that's why you only experience the slowness on the initial load. Can you make these images smaller?

Comment: I also noticed that. When you bypass cache by doing Ctrl+F5 it takes a lot of time. However Goalie says he's getting the issue when debugging and that's not consistent with images and styles being the cause. All this should be in cache by that time.

Comment: Those photos are actually from the page I ultimately redirect to (niagaragradschool.net).  The domain my project is on that redirects, is niagaragradschool.com)

Comment: Try commenting out those links loading the images and see if performance improves.

Comment: Remove all instances of images and external code. With any CSS and JS, I would make a bundle and have it optimize it. This will reduce the lode time or if you can offload it to a very fast CDN. After that, check it out. I have bundled entire JS/CSS packages with the optimize flag and it usually reduces my load time by a few seconds easily. Plus it will be minified by default so it will make it smaller and harder for someone else to copy.